# How to rename system generated constraint name and index of primary key

Tags: sql, oracle12c

As the title says I need to rename a primary key constraint that has name 
sys_ 000545 and the same name is for the index name. How can I achive this in oracle pl/sql. The name is random.

I tried using alter index with subquery that selects the index name but oracle does not allow this.

EDIT
I need this rename as part of update script

Comment: Can you share if any of the solutions present on the first page of a google search for 'Oracle rename index' work for you?

Comment: @dfundako The solutions that i found can't be used as update script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SQL> create table test (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C009641

SQL> alter table test rename constraint sys_c009641 to pk_test;

Table altered.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
PK_TEST

SQL>
```

---

```
SQL> select index_name from user_indexes where table_name = 'TEST';

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C009641

SQL> alter index sys_c009641 rename to pk_test;

Index altered.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes where table_name = 'TEST';

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
PK_TEST

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: a script requires dynamic SQL]**

```
SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table test (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C009643

SQL> declare
  2    l_table_name user_tables.table_name%type := 'TEST';
  3    l_pk user_constraints.constraint_name%type;
  4  begin
  5    select constraint_name
  6      into l_pk
  7      from user_constraints
  8      where table_name = l_table_name
  9        and constraint_type = 'P';
 10
 11    execute immediate 'alter table ' || l_table_name || ' rename constraint ' ||
 12                      l_pk || ' to pk_' || l_table_name;
 13  end;
 14  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
PK_TEST

SQL>
```

Comment: I need update script i need to somehow store first select in variable and use it in alter

Comment: A script requires dynamic SQL. I have updated my answer, have a look. It shows how to do it with a primary key; do the same for the index.

Comment: Execute immediate is what i need thank you, i assume it is the same command for altering the index